# Why Java is not using VarHandle for collection classes the way it is using it for AtomicReferenceArray?

Tags: java, collections, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

By using VarHandle class in Java you can achieve atomic operations on objects, through which classes like AtomicReferenceArray can perform concurrent operations on elements of array without locking (synchronized) the whole array structure ending up in significant performance gain.

Is there any specific reason why other synchronized and thread safe versions of collections are not implementing such model?
For example all the synchronized factory methods in Collections class return the version of their corresponding collection that uses synchronized methods which locks the whole collection!

Comment: Atomic operations on objects don't make a whole collection necessarily thread-safe.  The synchronized factory methods in Collections, for example, are the only way to make _arbitrary_ collection implementations thread-safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atomic operations on objects don't make a whole collection necessarily thread-safe. The synchronized factory methods in Collections, for example, are the only way to make arbitrary collection implementations thread-safe.

It is possible that `VarHandle` could be used to optimize collections specifically built for concurrency, such as `ConcurrentHashMap`.  If you think that `VarHandle`s could be used to improve those types, you should file a feature request.  It's entirely possible that just nobody's bothered to do it.

Comment: Some of j.u.c. is avoiding using `VarHandles` due to static initialization ordering, which caused problems for `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` when it tried to switch over. Just an fyi that some cases their usage of `Unsafe` is intentional to avoid dependency problems.

Comment: @BenManes Thanks Ben for mentioning so. Just to double check are you referring to problems like following bug? https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8277090?jql=project%20%3D%2010100%20AND%20component%20%3D%2010300%20AND%20cf%5B10008%5D%20%3D%20215

Comment: @alpal yep, that is the one. The [issue](https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-java-agent/issues/558) that my library's users had was this [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8274349), but we thought it was an initialization error at first.

Comment: @alpal You’ll probably want to look at jctools. You’re welcome to email me if I can be of help.

Comment: It’s possible that the concurrent collections will be rewritten to use `VarHandle` anyway, as part of the effort to finally get rid of `sun.misc.Unsafe`.